# How do I get the treasure in the Sealed Door section of the Sealed Palace(5-3)?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

The hint for this one is...

> There is, very rarely, a reward for cowards.

In response to this, I've tried not attacking the enemies, refusing to enter into the big open area for a minute, running around at the edge of the area, hiding in a corner, and generally being a total wuss. Nothing seems to happen.

How do I get the treasure here?

Answer (score 1):

To my great irritation, it seems as though you can't obtain this treasure while in Practice Mode. I got it by completing the level in Story Mode, running back to the previous stage, coming back into the level, running into the center, and then heading back up the stairs to the previous level.

Your reward here is...

> ...The Rocket Glove! It gives you a massive +60 boost to your attack power. Yes, that's all. I'm rather unimpressed by the fact that it gives me no rocket powers.